# on change of language languageService.getAll() data is not changing

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I wanted to display all languages with their names.

test.html

```
 <ul>
       <li *ngFor="let item of (allLangs$ | async)">
         <a (click)="changeLanguage(item.isocode)">
           <span>{{item.name}}</span>
         </a>
       </li>
     </ul>
```

component.ts

```
    export class CmsSiteContextComponent {
      allLangs$: Observable<Language[]> = this.languageService.getAll();
      activeLangString: string;
    
      constructor(
        protected languageService: LanguageService,
      ) {
    
        this.languageService.getActive().subscribe((lng) => {
          this.activeLangString = lng;
        });
    
        this.allLangs$.subscribe((allLangs) => {
          console.log('allLangs ', allLangs);
        });
      }
    
      public changeLanguage(key: string): void {
        this.languageService.setActive(key);
      }
    }
```

languageService.getAll()``` language data(name, nativename) is not updated without reload.

want to change names in html without reloading the page.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide some context code, if possible a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is explicitly dispatch the `LoadLanguages` action when you want to update the language data: `store.dispatch(new SiteContextActions.LoadLanguages())`.

The another way is to add a meta reducer to clear the SiteContextState for action `SiteContextActions.LANGUAGE_CHANGE`.

Comment: Actually, we want to show a list of languages in UI and then click on change language we would like show those languages names in the respective language.